# Why is OnItemClickListener not working with ListView within a Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I am at my wits end trying to find a solution to this problem. I am unable to make OnItemClickListener work with my listview. While an analogous code is working perfectly fine with gridview. Here is my code.

```
public class Songs extends ListFragment implements /*AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,*/ LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

SongsAdapter nAdapter;
private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

private int position;

public static Songs newInstance(int position) {
    Songs f = new Songs();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs, container, false);
    nAdapter = new SongsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
    setListAdapter(nAdapter);

   /* listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    });*/



    return myFragmentView;
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    //ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.attachToListView(getListView());




    //getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
/*
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayer.class).putExtra("position", position).putExtra("orderby", orderby).putExtra("selection", selection).putExtra("val", val));
}

*/
```

I have tried everything including implementing OnItemClickListener to overriding OnListItemClick. But absolutely nothing seems to work.

Here is the layout of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/metalList">


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/listdivider"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/songlist_selector"/>
<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shuffle_48"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/mm1"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/mm2"
    fab:fab_shadow="true"
    />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: add your ListView Intitialization in your **onCreate()** method before assigning the onItemClickListener to the listview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnItemClickListener()` like below

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                     int itm=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                switch (itm) {
                case 0:
                Toast.makeText(m_context, "Item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                  Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent1);
                              break;

        }
    });
```